# What format and content-type is the body of a paypal rest access token call?

Tags: java, rest, paypal, jersey

I am using Java with Jersey 2.0 client to make a REST call to the paypal REST API. According to the API doc, I should be making a post to: https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token with the Accept: application/json and Accept-Language: en_US. It also indicates that I should pass in the body grant_type=client_credentials. I do all this but I keep getting a 406 or 415. What I can't figure out is what the Content-Type of the post call should be? I've tried text/plain, text/html, application/json, form-url-encoded.. nothing seems to get me a token back. Not sure why their API doc writer didn't include the Content-Type and format of the payload in the documentation. Anyone know what the Content-Type should be for the body of the post?

I'd like to add that when I do any Content-Type other than form-url-encoded, I get back 415, which means mediatype not accepted, however when I pass in anything using form-url-encoded, I get back the 406, which basically tells me the body is not acceptable.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure that your request body is correct and in the right format?

Comment: Hi, I am sure that the mediatype should be form_url_encoded and from the examples I have, that is what I am passing. Only other issue I can think of is perhaps I am not using SSL right.. the url is https, but I am not using SSL on my client side.. not sure if the sandbox requires SSL or not for the actual request. I will be trying to use that next.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for bringing up the question.

There was a recent change in the /token call and requests for an access token need to have the `content-type` set as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. This is done by default in cURL calls.

Updated docs that include a note about this will be going out very soon.

Answer (score 0):

Inbound the OAuth 2 endpoint only accepts "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" or it will throw a 415, the payload then needs to be properly url encoded.  Likewise the accepts header needs to contain "application/json", or the service will throw a 406.

For example:

Headers:
Authorization: Basic [base64 encoded]
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Accepts: application/json

Payload sample:
grant_type=client_credentials&response_type=token